# How to get end and start point of all lines of a hierarchical tree?

Tags: sql, sqlite

I have an SQLite DB with a bench of different hierarchical trees (similar to the image below), where I only want to get the start and the end points of each tree line.
[image]
In **blue** are the tree IDs (called ws_id), in **green** are the wanted start and end points and in **red** the unwanted objects between start and end points.

Here a data example with the same structure as the hierarchical tree above and a similar data structure to mine:

```
CREATE TABLE feat_link
(ws_id integer, source_node varchar(10), target_node varchar(10));
ALTER TABLE feat_link ADD PRIMARY KEY (ws_id);
INSERT INTO feat_link
VALUES ('b', '1', '36');
INSERT INTO feat_link
VALUES ('b', '1', '17');
INSERT INTO feat_link
VALUES ('b', '36', '21');   
INSERT INTO feat_link
VALUES ('b', '2', '20');
INSERT INTO feat_link
VALUES ('b', '3', '37');  
INSERT INTO feat_link
VALUES ('b', '37', '24');
```

As you can see the source_node value is only match with the next target_node value and not to the final node of a tree line. What I need is matching (I think recursive query), that first recognises which source_nodes are really the beginninig of a tree (attention, for example B is not expected) and which is the last point of that line. The further value columns are not relevant.

Here is my expected result:
[image]

What we tried so far were RECURSIVE queries. Here an example assuming that my data table above is called "feat_link":

```
WITH RECURSIVE target(x) AS (
  SELECT (select 1 from feat_link)
  UNION ALL 
  SELECT feat_link.target_node
  FROM feat_link, target
  WHERE feat_link.source_node=target.x 
    AND feat_link.source_node IS NOT NULL 
    and feat_link.ws_id = 'B'
) 
select distinct x from target;
```

Do you have any ideas how to improve the code or even a better idea? We only get sometimes a return and the results seem not to be always true.

Answer (score 0):

First, enumerate all possible lines (wanted and unwanted) in the standard way:

```
WITH RECURSIVE lines(ws_id, source_node, target_node) AS (
  -- start with all nodes that have no link to their start
  SELECT ws_id, source_node, target_node
  FROM feat_link
  WHERE (ws_id, source_node) NOT IN (SELECT ws_id, target_node
                                     FROM feat_link)

  UNION ALL

  SELECT l.ws_id, l.source_node, f.target_node
  FROM feat_link f
  JOIN lines l ON (f.ws_id, f.source_node) = (l.ws_id, l.target_node)
)
...
```

Then filter out all lines that are part of a longer line, i.e., that have a link from their end:

```
...
SELECT *
FROM lines
WHERE (ws_id, target_node) NOT IN (SELECT ws_id, source_node
                                   FROM feat_link);
```